# separate screen for output in R?

Tags: r, rstudio, sink

I am using RStudio for my project, I want a separate screen for the output. I tried with `sink()`, but I need a new pop up window. My code is

```
vd<-data.frame()
vd<-c("V1","V2")
vf<-length(vd)
i<-1
while(i<=vf){
vd<-c("V1","V2")
#print(vd)
leng<-length(vd)
selectru<-combn(vd,leng)
#print(selectru)
print(selectru[i])
fst<-selectru[i]
select<-data.frame()
select<-selectru[selectru[,1]!=selectru[i],]
m<-length(select)
select<-combn(select,m)
snd <-apply(select,2,function(rows) paste0(rows, collapse = ""))
cat(sprintf("\"%s\" =>\"%s\"\n", fst,snd))
i<-i+1
}
```

These data is not the actual one, just example data.

Is it possible to show the output "ONLY" in a separate screen or browser window? no need to show any graph or plot operation.

Comment: There is an export button on top of the plot in RStudio if you want to send it to file or pdf.

Comment: okay,i think that export work for  polting graph and  image only ?.

Comment: I don't know what you want this for, but you probably should have a look at knitr.

Comment: @Roland Actually I want a separate screen that contain my code output only.
like sink() function ;get the output in notepad.Problem with sink() function is each time we need looking place it saved and open that notepad .is there any viewer screen for my code output in R studio or is it possible to show my output in browser ?

Comment: tanks roland.knitr is good.but i think this not working for imported dataset instead of entering current data in console

Comment: sorry it working for all dataset.thanks roland

Comment: Take a look at the package **rite**. It will give you an output widget like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per my comment, here's an example using the `sinkstart` function from [**rite**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rite/).

Code:

```
library(rite)
sinkstart(echo=FALSE)
# your code
# close the widget with the X or
# use `sinkstop()` to turn off the `sink`ing
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: .this way i expect the ouput.

Comment: .is it possible to find any output file after r code execution.(what i meant is like exe file created after C code execution  ).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. This saves to two `tempfile()`'s in R's temporary session directory, so you could look for the files there. Otherwise, you have save the output manually with a `<ctrl-s>` on the keyboard or by accessing the right-click context menu on the widget.

Comment: i think its not working.shall i asking this as another question in stack over flow.?.

Comment: i am using Win 8.i saved ouput file.but nothing will happened after opening it.just one CMD is opened and show front end of R.I am a beginner in R.please explain it how to worked it?

Comment: So you were able to save the output to a file, but then you couldn't open the file in a text editor?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45724/discussion-between-user3090597-and-thomas)

Comment: Works beautifully. From R-studio either from the console or from source, output is sent to a simple new window.  Finally, I can see what I'm doing without moving panes up and down all day!  Thank you Thomas!

Comment: Package ‘rite’ was removed from the CRAN repository? What is the alternative?